# How to convert a nanosecond precision epoch timestamp to a datetime in Julia

Tags: julia

In Python's Pandas library, it's simple to create a datetime from a nanosecond-precision unix timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.to_datetime(1543190400010159332, unit='ns')
print(ts)
```

displays

`2018-11-26 00:00:00.010159332`

It's also trivial to recover the original timestamp, by `ts.value`.

Is there a library that provides equivalent functionality in Julia? I found the TimesDates library provides nanosecond-precision `TimeDate`s, but I couldn't find [examples in the documentation](https://jeffreysarnoff.github.io/TimesDates.jl/latest/examples/) showing how to create a `TimesDates.TimeDate` directly from a nanosecond precision timestamp.

Comment: I think [AstroTime.jl](https://github.com/JuliaAstro/AstroTime.jl) does this, but have not used it myself, and it might be overkill for what you are after. There is also a Discourse thread on this topic [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/higher-resolution-datetime-timestamp/3069).

Comment: Never used julia but can you not use: `TimeDate("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + Nanosecond(1543190400010159332)`?

Comment: @NickA Nanosecond(1543190400010159332) doesn't work if the last three digits are zero. hckr's answer works.

Comment: Also, precision does not correspond to resolution. I think this question asks about resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.to_datetime` has an `origin` parameter that is `unix` by default (`1970-01-01T00:00:00`).

```
using TimesDates, Dates
val = 1543190400010159332
sec = val ÷ 10^9
ms = val ÷ 10^6 - sec * 10^3
ns = val % 10^6
origin = TimeDate(unix2datetime(sec))
ms = Millisecond(ms)
ns = Nanosecond(ns)
result = origin + ms + ns
```

This gives `2018-11-26T00:00:00.010159332`.

You can now turn it into a function.

Comment: It seems that doesn't work for all values, e.g. 1543190400010159000 nanoseconds. If I do

origin = TimesDates.TimeDate(Dates.unix2datetime(0))
ns = TimesDates.Nanosecond(1543190400010159000)
origin + ns

Then it fails with

"ArgumentError: Millisecond: 1543190400010 out of range (0:999)

Stacktrace:
 [1] Dates.Time(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/jonathan.barnard/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Dates/src/types.jl:224
 [2] Dates.Time(::Dates.CompoundPeriod) at /home/jonathan.barnard/.julia/packages/CompoundPeriods/ZMMk9/src/misc.jl:34"